# Matlab: Update waitbar without drawing plot

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot

I'm trying to plot lots of single lines with different length. Therefore, I use a rather simple code:

```
p = csvread('C:\path\file.csv',2,0,[2,0,1000000,3]);
h=waitbar(0,'Plotting...');
for r=1:size(p,1)
    waitbar(r/size(p,1),h);
    r0=r;
    t0=p(r0,4);
    while(r<=size(p,1) && p(r,4)==t0)
        r=r+1;
    end
    plot(p(r0:r-1,2),p(r0:r-1,3));
    hold on
end
close(h);
```

This code iterates through each line of my csv file and plots the lines from `r0` to `r-1` for which `p(r,4)` stays constant. I am not interested in seeing every single line being plotted, so I want Matlab to plot everything in the background and show me the result afterwards. Since that plotting takes quite some time, I'd like to see my waitbar updating while plotting in the background.

But there's a problem: everytime the waitbar updates, the plot is drawn (similar to the `drawnow` command). This takes A LOT of time compared to drawing in the background. **How can I update my waitbar without drawing the plot?**

Comment: I suggest not updating the waitbar through every iteration of the loop, because it's computationally expensive. Instead, update every 100th iteration. Use the mod function.
if mod(r,100)==0
.. update waitbar..
end

Comment: Have you tried to plot all at once? This may require more memory, but it should be faster.

Comment: @patrik's suggestion is probably the best you can do if you can afford to store all the data in one array.

Comment: @patrik For plotting them all at once, they would need to be of equal length, wouldn't they? That would of course be the preferred option but I could not get this to work yet.

I did also try to update the waitbar every nth iteration; I just removed it to keep the code as short as possible. Anyway, that would only be a workaround and not a soultion afterall.

Comment: @Dominic ok I see, however, just moving the waitbar and count on that the plot will not be drawn is not really safe. That will make the plot appear at random occasions. Further, yes there is a drawnow in `waitbar` :)

Comment: @patrik Can't believe I did not try `edit waitbar` before. Indeed, there is a `drawnow` command in there - so there's no way to avoid it at all. Using an invisible figure is the best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set(h,'Visible','off');` to hide the plot until you need to see it. This only offers about a 25% speed reduction based on some quick tests I ran, however.

For example:

```
h = figure(1);              %// get figure handle
set(h,'Visible','off')      %// hide plot window
hold on;
t = -10:0.1:10;             %// create curves on the plot
plot(t,sin(t),'b');         
plot(t,sin(t+2*pi/3),'r');
plot(t,sin(t-2*pi/3),'g');
set(h,'Visible','on');      %// draw plot
```

Comment: I guess that's as close as one can get. In this case, the most time is consumed by the `waitbar`command. I'm fine with that (because that's easy to control with a `mod` condition) and appreciate your help!

Comment: @Dominic patrik's suggestion offers more than a 2x speed up if you can get it working. Just remember to pre-allocate the array containing all your plot data with `zeros` if you do--otherwise it will have a far worse performance.

Comment: I did manage to plot all lines at once - allocating `NaN` does work. For my specific problem, it's hard to know the number of lines and their maximum length beforehand. Still, your answer was the closest thing possible to my question - even though their might be a better solution for my problem afterall.